# connected by months

Tags: oracle, list, date

Ok, I'm new using this `connect by` thing. But its always quite useful. I have this small problem you guys might be able to help me...

Given start month (say `to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMM')`) and end month (say, `to_char(add_months(sysdate, 6),'YYYYMM')`), want to get the list of months in between, in the same format.

Well, I want to use this into a partitions automation script. My best shot so far (pretty pitiful) yields invalid months e.g.'201034'... (and yea, I know, incredibly inefficient)

Follows the code:

```
SELECT id
from
    (select to_char(add_months(sysdate, 6),'YYYYMM') as tn_end, to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMM') as tn_start from dual) tabla,
    (select * from
        (Select Level as Id from dual connect by Level <= (Select to_char(add_months(sysdate, 1),'YYYYMM')from dual)) where id > to_char(sysdate,'YYYYMM')) t
Where 
    t.Id between tabla.tn_start and tabla.tn_end
```

how do I do to make this query return only valid months? Any tips?

cheers mates,

f.

Comment: It would be much easier to automate this with a loop in PL/SQL and it will be a lot more maintainable as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way might be to separate out the row generator from the date function. So generate a list from 0 to 6 and calculate months from that. If you want to pass the months in then do that in the with clause

```
with my_counter as (
  Select Level-1 as id 
  from dual 
  connect by Level <= 7
) 
select to_char(add_months(sysdate, id),'YYYYMM') from my_counter
```

The example below will allow you to plug in the dates you require to work out the difference.

```
with my_counter as (
  Select Level-1 as id 
  from dual 
  connect by level <= months_between(add_months(trunc(sysdate,'MM'), 6), 
      trunc(sysdate,'MM')) + 1
) 
select to_char(add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), id),'YYYYMM') from my_counter
```

Answer (score 1):

For generating dates and date ranges, I strongly suggest you create a permanent calendar table with one row for each day. Even if you keep 20 years in this table it will be small ~7500 rows. Having such a table lets you attach additional (potentially non-standard) information to a date. For example your company may use a 6-week reporting period which you cannot extract using TO_CHAR / TO_DATE. Pre-compute it and store it in this table.

Oh, and Oracle 11g has automatic partition management. If you are stuck with 10g, then this article may be of interest to you? [Automatic Partition Management for Oracle 10g](http://ocpdba.wordpress.com/2009/10/12/automatic-partition-management-for-oracle-10g/)

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks very much. Unfortunately I am stuck in 10g and I'm not (hehe, as my newbness makes obvious) the DBA, so have no access to these sort of things. Thanks for the heads up anyway. +1!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with numbers as
( select level as n from dual
  connect by level <= 7
)
select to_char (add_months (trunc(sysdate,'MM'), n-1), 'YYYYMM') id
from numbers;

ID
------
201012
201101
201102
201103
201104
201105
201106
```

Comment: straight in the face. Thanks mate.