# Oracle query to get month wise data and give 0 for month not available

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Following is my table data

```
time_stamp     Name
01-Mar-14      a
02-Mar-14      b
02-Mar-14      c
01-May-14      d
02-May-14      e
01-Jun-14      f
```

Output required:

```
(3,0,2,1) (Month wise count with 0 if month doesn't exist)
```

I have created the following query :

```
select 
 listagg(count(1),',') within group (order by EXTRACT(month FROM time_stamp)) 
from ps_bqueues_host 
where time_stamp BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Mar-14', 'DD-Mon-YY') and
  TO_DATE('01-Jun-14', 'DD-Mon-YY') GROUP BY EXTRACT(month FROM time_stamp)
```

This gives me the output :

```
(3,2,1) (Month of Apr with 0 is not there).
```

Please suggest how to group by on all months.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to join a _sub-select_ table that contains all months range. Then display the count(time_stamp) grouped by all listed months. Here you can see an exemple of how to populate a sub-select table with month : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375897/connected-by-months or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644562/oracle-sql-query-to-list-all-the-dates-of-previous-month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Join this original table with table with all months in given period. If it is inside one year then [we need 1,2,3,...12 sequence](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_Row_Generator_Techniques).

```
select 
 listagg(count(Name),',') within 
    group (order by m.rn) 
from 
     (SELECT * FROM  ps_bqueues_host 
      where time_stamp 
        BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Mar-14', 'DD-Mon-YY') 
        and     TO_DATE('01-Jun-14', 'DD-Mon-YY') 
     )   
RIGHT JOIN 
     (SELECT LEVEL rn FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12) m
     ON m.rn=EXTRACT(month FROM time_stamp)

WHERE m.rn BETWEEN EXTRACT(month FROM TO_DATE('01-Mar-14', 'DD-Mon-YY'))
           AND  EXTRACT(month FROM TO_DATE('01-Jun-14', 'DD-Mon-YY'))
GROUP BY m.rn
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d43ef1/7)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the help but the output is incorrect. Using your query, output is (0,0,7050,0). However, the count of month may is 5274 using the below query : select count(time_stamp) from ps_bqueues_host where time_stamp BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-May-14', 'DD-Mon-YY') and TO_DATE('31-May-14', 'DD-Mon-YY'). The expected result is (0,0,5274,0)

Comment: Does time_stamp field contain time part? If so then your query doesn't count the latest day of 31.05.2014 try to use `and TO_DATE('01-Jun-14', 'DD-Mon-YY')` instead of `31 May 2014`.

Comment: That's right. '01-Jun-14' worked. Please suggest how to handle this? I mean is there a way to include the last day data also without querying till the next day?

Comment: It is because `31-May-2014 23:00:01` > '31-May-2014'. You should add a day for example `...and TO_DATE('31-May-14', 'DD-Mon-YY')+1` or add time `..and To_date('31-May-2014 23:59:59','mm-Mon-yy hh24:mi:ss')`

Comment: I opted To_date('31-May-2014 23:59:59','mm-Mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') and it works. Thanks for the help!